# Only perform action for specific sub classes of objects

Tags: java, oop

How can I apply an action only for specific sub classes of objects in an object oriented way in Java based on the SOLID principles?

Eg, currently I would do something like this:

```
public void WorkerMethod(Result result) {
   // processing code
   // ...
   // finish processing code, now save

   if (result instanceof ModelResult || result instanceof DataResult || ...) 
      databaseClient.saveStringData(GetDataToSave(result));
   else ; // I don't want to save these objects
}
```

I thought one way of doing it would be to extend my Result class and add a "shouldSave()" method which returns false by default. Then override it for subclasses I want to save, but this doesn't feel right / feels hacky / code smell.

What is the correct OOP way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: For clarity, I suggest you fix your example code to comply with Java naming conventions. Method names start with a lowercase letter. `WorkerMethod` should be `workerMethod`, same for `GetDataToSave`.

Comment: The call to `GetDataToSave` seems like a distraction from your core question. And  it is a possible code smell: Why can't a `Result` report its own data to save?

Comment: I believe more OOP will be to avoid class extension at all. Create several interfaces, for each class to implement, perhaps by some specific behavior. Create collections of object by types of their interfaces and iterate them. This way avoiding reflection and using using instanceOf.